# (Should/If) any consent of the employer (be/is) required, you should take it

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Which one is correct ?

Should/**if** any consent of the employer **is** required, you should take it.

or

Should/**if** any consent of the employer **be** required, you should take it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Should** any consent of the employer **be** required, you should take it.

..**should** is a modal verb, and modal verbs take "bare infinitives" (verbs in their basic form and without the particle *to*). **Be** is such "bare infinitive" verb. Hence, we have a combination **should + be** (modal verb + bare infinitive).

Compare:

> 1. I **am** glad. She **is** glad. (no modal verbs; the form of the verb depends on the subject: "I" and "She" use different forms of "to be": "am", "is")
> 2. I **should be** glad. She **should be** glad. (modal verb *should* makes us use the same basic form of "to be": "be" instead of "am" or "is")
> 3. I **should am** glad. She **should is** glad. (WRONG!)

---

> **If** any consent of the employer **is** required, you should take it.

..here you don't need to place the verb into the bare infinitive form, because it is not attached to a modal verb.

Comment: there is another problem that I cannot understand. can you confirm the correctness of the following sentence ? Microsoft word is trying to "correct" it; "Should he demands a specific design from the Contractor which goes beyond the requirements(e.g. the previous design); a Variation shall lead this demand." it is trying to convert "demands" to "demand"

Comment: @Oguz **should + demand** (modal verb + basic form). "Demands" is not the basic form of the verb, it has the **s** ending. When you have a connection "modal verb + verb", you should use the basic form ("demand").